# UTF-8 & Unicode, what's with 0xC0 and 0x80?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I've been reading about Unicode and UTF-8 in the last couple of days and I often come across a bitwise comparison similar to this :

```
int strlen_utf8(char *s) 
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while (s[i]) 
  {
    if ((s[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) j++;
    i++;
  }
  return j;
}
```

Can someone clarify the comparison with 0xc0 and checking if it's the most significant bit ?

Thank you!

EDIT: ANDed, not comparison, used the wrong word ;)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

It's not a comparison with `0xc0`, it's a logical AND operation with `0xc0`.

The bit mask `0xc0` is `11 00 00 00` so what the AND is doing is extracting only the top two bits:

```
    ab cd ef gh
AND 11 00 00 00
    -- -- -- --
  = ab 00 00 00
```

This is then compared to `0x80` (binary `10 00 00 00`). In other words, the `if` statement is checking to see if the top two bits of the value are not equal to `10`.

"Why?", I hear you ask. Well, that's a good question. The answer is that, in UTF-8, all bytes that begin with the bit pattern `10` are subsequent bytes of a multi-byte sequence:

```
                    UTF-8
Range              Encoding  Binary value
-----------------  --------  --------------------------
U+000000-U+00007f  0xxxxxxx  0xxxxxxx

U+000080-U+0007ff  110yyyxx  00000yyy xxxxxxxx
                   10xxxxxx

U+000800-U+00ffff  1110yyyy  yyyyyyyy xxxxxxxx
                   10yyyyxx
                   10xxxxxx

U+010000-U+10ffff  11110zzz  000zzzzz yyyyyyyy xxxxxxxx
                   10zzyyyy
                   10yyyyxx
                   10xxxxxx
```

So, what this little snippet is doing is going through every byte of your UTF-8 string and counting up all the bytes that aren't continuation bytes (i.e., it's getting the length of the string, as advertised). See [this wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for more detail and [Joel Spolsky's excellent article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for a primer.

---

An interesting aside by the way. You can classify bytes in a UTF-8 stream as follows:

- With the high bit set to `0`, it's a single byte value.
- With the two high bits set to `10`, it's a continuation byte.
- Otherwise, it's the first byte of a multi-byte sequence and the number of leading `1` bits indicates how many bytes there are in total for this sequence (`110...` means two bytes, `1110...` means three bytes, etc).