# Detecting multibyte character sequences?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I'm writing a parser which parses UTF-8 strings. Characters outside of the ASCII range can only occur inside of string literals, which begin and end with `'` or `"`. The rest of the language may only contain ASCII characters, so I can simply return an error if I find a byte outside the ASCII range.

The problem I can't seem to figure out is, when I encounter a non-ASCII character inside of a string literal, how can I detect how many bytes to skip for that character? My concern is that if a multi-byte character contains a `'` or `"` as one of the bytes, my parser would end the string literal early.

Perhaps a shorter way to ask this is, if I encounter a byte in the `0x80`-`0xFF` range, how can I detect how many bytes are in that character in a UTF-8 encoded string?

I'm writing this parser in C but I suspect that doesn't matter.

Comment: Why do you want to _skip_ the bytes? You'd need to actually decode them, won't you? And you'd also want to verify that the sequence is valid. Assuming that a supposed UTF-8 encoded untrusted string is actually valid UTF-8 is a common cause for vulnerabilities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly skip unicode (UTF-8) characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046533/how-to-correctly-skip-unicode-utf-8-characters)

Comment: I understand that your question is independent of any specific programming language, but since you are using C I added a `[c]` tag to increase the audience for your question. Feel free to remove it.

Comment: The first table in Wikipedia shows it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding

Answer (score 7):

> My concern is that if a multi-byte character contains a ' or " as one of the bytes, my parser would end the string literal early.

Ah, this is your misunderstanding. The brilliance of UTF-8 is that this cannot happen. In UTF-8, the byte 0x27 can *only* mean APOSTROPHE. It can never be part of a multi-byte sequence. This is because continuation bytes begin with the high bit set to 1.

A major design goal of UTF-8 is that existing and naïve ASCII implementations will work identically when parsing UTF-8 streams, even if the stream includes non-ASCII bytes. You can safely parse for `"` and continue to accumulate bytes until you reach `"` (and use `\` to escape internal `"`), and never have to worry about whether there are multi-byte characters involved with UTF-8. ASCII parsers do not need to understand UTF-8 or perform any UTF-8 decoding in order to work correctly.

Beyond that, if you decide you really do want to know the answer to your question, the first byte's number of leading 1 bits tells you the length, with the exception that zero 1s is "1 byte" and one 1 is "continuation".

```
0x00 - 0x7F -> 1 byte
0x80 - 0xBF -> (continuation)
0xC0 - 0xDF -> 2 bytes
0xE0 - 0xEF -> 3 bytes
0xF0 - 0xF7 -> 4 bytes
```

You can also just keep scanning along until you find something in the range 0x00-0x7F.